# openGauss gsql connection database, prompted “unknow:26000”

Tags: connection

The gsql connection database (port number determines no problem), prompted，prompted “failed to connect Unknow:26000”，as illustrated in following figure：
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ET61.png

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the port 26000 exists and confirm whether the port and service of openGauss are started